# Dynamically create sql where condition on textbox entry

Tags: sql, where-clause, dynamic-sql

I am working on a C# desktop application. I want to create a search functionality. Now the problem is that i am using around 8 textboxes. Different permutations of textboxes could be populated and the resulting 'sql where' condition should only include those textboxes values which are not null. Now one pathetic way is to use a zillion 'if and else' which obviously is laborious. Any other way to do this?

Comment: If you use an ORM like Entity Framework, this becomes a piece of cake by using the *composable* `IQueryable` interface. .....

Comment: unfortunately i am not.any other logic?

Answer (score 0):

You need just one query with filled WHERE to use all parameters like this

```
select ...
from ...
WHERE
    (firstNameColumn=:firstNameParam or :firstNameParam is null)
AND (lastNameColumn=:lastNameParam or :lastNameParam is null)
AND (...)
```

Comment: I am using it like this and its not working.


query = "select * from Customer join Orders on Customer.ID = Orders.Customer_ID join Order_Line on Orders.ID = Order_Line.Order_ID where (Customer.ID = " + customer_id + " or Customer.ID is null ) and (Customer.Cell1 = '" + cellnum + "' or  Customer.Cell1 is null ) and (Orders.ID = " + order_id + " or Orders.ID is null ) and (Order_Line.Name = '" + item_name + "' or Order_Line.Name is null) and (Order_Line.Model = '" + item_model + "' or Order_Line.Model is null ) and (Orders.Total_Cost = " + total_cost + " or Orders.Total_Cost is null)  ";

Comment: It's wrong as you described. You must compare with null parameter not column value

Comment: I tried that aswel. Instead of using Table.column for firstNameParam i am using the variable i used to get textbox values. Could you modify the above sql so i may get to know more?

Comment: I think you guys have misunderstanding here: Saqib is tryint to generate query in C#, while the answer is aimed at SQL, f.e. the body of stored procedure. If you have parameters of the procedure and are passing all the values of your filters, then you would could use this approach. I would also change this to check is parameter null first: `@firstNameParam is null or FirstNameColumn=@firstNameParam`. 
If parameter is null means search box was empty so it shouldn't influence the search. You can't use it in C# approach as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make a point of first checking is the paramtere null, then use it to compare with column values.

Since you are generating query in C#, try old-Chinese approach from Ming period of using default condition `where 1=1` just to avoid checking did you already had first condition :)

```
string query = "select ... from ... join ... on ... where 1=1";
//suposedly you have value of one search box in variable called "item_name"
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item_name) == false)
{
  query += " and Order_Line.Name ='" + item_name + "'";
}
```

and so on for other fields.

What you are trying to do in order to avoid ifs is not really a good approach. Look at this:

```
string query = " select ... where Order_Line.Name = '" + item_name + "'";
```

What will be the resulting string if item_name is actually null?

EDIT: the resulting query would be

```
where Order_Line.Name = '' or Order_Line.Name is null
```

which is not what you want. You want every row if that search field is empty, menaing it shouldn't have anu effect on search. That's why you need condition to see will you include this column in `where` clause in the first place.

Comment: Building queries by concatenating strings is almost always a **very bad** idea, especially if it comes from user input! It is asking for a SQL injection attack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: I agree, but he is alredy doing the same thing, just without conditions. He can add validation of the fields to reduce the risk.